# Page menus are jumping on hover

Tags: css, button

When hovering on my second menus (can be found there: http://justxp.plutohost.net/survive/index.html)

the items are jumping.

It happened once I added a background with padding to them, well that's what it needs to have, but it should just appear, not jump?

My code:

HTML + CSS can be found here:

http://pastebin.com/cbLDRefB

thanks.

Comment: Remove nav6 a:hover {padding: 21px;} and give a{padding: 21px;} instead.

Answer (score 0):

For not jumping you should not change the size of the elements on hover

you have

```
.nav6 a:hover {
    padding: 21px;
}
```

so you need to add padding to the all links not only `:hover`

```
.nav6 a {
    padding: 21px;
}
```

Comment: Then how people make these big backgrounds on hover?

Comment: set padding to all links, not just hovered

Comment: Thanks!

How do I set same bg size hover for all items? cause at the moment it depending on the text size

Comment: @user1604220 , sorry, I did not understand you comment. What do you actually want?

Comment: http://gyazo.com/37335cdec44cc22e2e691b2cb686a469
I want every menu item to have the same sized box on hover, if not possible, then a bit smaller but connects to the other hover box next to it if you know what I mean.

Comment: Actually I did not understand what you want. If you want the same size for all your menu options then you must be sure that they all will have the same (at least not bigger) amount of text. Cause if you set a width explicitly to option (`li {width:50px}` e.g.) and text is dynamically generated via some server script then it will all mess up